# Flag provided but not defined

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile, delve

I have following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.9.2

ADD . /go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet
ADD . /go/src/github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv

RUN go install github.com/golang/example/outyet
RUN go install github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet/bootstrap.sh"]
CMD ["/go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet/bootstrap.sh"]

EXPOSE 8091
EXPOSE 5432
```

And following `bootstrap.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
go build -gcflags='-N -l' github.com/golang/example/outyet && 
dlv --listen=:5432 --headless=true --api-version=2 exec outyet;
```

After running container and image with following lines:

```
sudo docker build -t outyet .
sudo docker run -p 6060:8091 -p 5432:5432  --name test --rm outyet
```

I get following output:

```
flag provided but not defined: -listen
Usage of dlv:
  -http string
        Listen address (default ":8091")
  -poll duration
        Poll period (default 1s)
  -version string
        Go version (default "1.4")
```

When I run bootstrap.sh locally on my ubuntu hostmachine everything works fine. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it, my `Dockerfile` looks like this now:

```
FROM golang:1.9.2

ADD . /go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet

RUN go install github.com/golang/example/outyet
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet/bootstrap.sh"]
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/go/bin/outyet"]

CMD ["/go/src/github.com/golang/example/outyet/bootstrap.sh"]

EXPOSE 8091
EXPOSE 5432
```

bootstrap.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
go get github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv;
go build -gcflags='-N -l' github.com/golang/example/outyet && 
dlv --listen=:5432 --headless=true --api-version=2 exec outyet
```

And run it as following:

```
sudo docker build -t outyet .
sudo docker run --security-opt=seccomp:unconfined --net=host  --name test --rm outyet
```